# Why doesn't ST_Intersects work with multiple rows of geom

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, st-intersects

I am new to PostGIS. I am trying to find the conditional intersection between two multi-polygons PostGIS tables (`tab1` and `tab2`) when `tab2` meets certain criteria (defined by row values of one of the columns). I am using the following `SQL`

```
SELECT *
FROM tab1 
WHERE ST_Intersects(tab1.geom, (SELECT geom FROM tab2 WHERE "cond_column" = 'selected_string'));
```

But I get the following error

```
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I totally understand the error and I know I have selected multiple rows of multi-polygon from tab2. But my thinking is that `ST_intersect` will check for each row of both `tab1.geom` and the selected rows of `tab2.geom`. Why isn't this the case and what's the right way to do this? And in general, is it a good practice to use a subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a subquery, you can only use it in a function made for the number of line returned, so if your sub-query returns multiple rows you need to use it in an aggregate function. I think what you want to do is a join between the 2 tables. To do that, you can do it for example like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM tab1
INNER JOIN (SELECT geom FROM tab2 WHERE "cond_column" = 'selected_string') as tab2_filtered 
ON ST_Intersects(tab1.geom, tab2_filtered.geom)
```

Personally, I prefer to use CTE for easier to read code:

```
WITH tab2_filtered AS (
  SELECT geom FROM tab2 WHERE "cond_column" = 'selected_string'
)
SELECT
  *
FROM tab1
INNER JOIN tab2_filtered 
ON ST_Intersects(tab1.geom, tab2_filtered.geom)
```

EDIT:

This type of join is efficient because it will uses indexes on geometry (if
you made them).
If you only want a filtering on your `tab1`, you can also use the `EXISTS` command:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM tab1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tab2 WHERE "cond_column" = 'selected_string' AND ST_Intersects(tab1.geom, tab2.geom)
)
```

I just checked, this command will use the index on tab2 too (`road_arc` is `tab1` and `admin_boundary` is `tab2`):
[image]

Comment: so my understanding is that the `inner_join` do something similar to `st_collect` from @Ian Turton's suggestion? Is that correct?

Comment: With an `INNER JOIN` you get the join between your two table, which will keep the rows from tab1 where there is an intersection with the geom in tab2. But there is 2 main differences with Ian answer: 1) you will have the info of the tab2 where you intersects (you can add them by adding `tab2.*` in the select) which can be interesting to get the name of the zone for ex, and 2) you will have duplicate rows if your tab1 geom intersects with multiple geom in tab2 (you can remove them with a `distinct` if you don't want them)

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. Just to confirm - if I ONLY need the columns of tab1 where `tab1.geom` intersects with `tab2.geom` then Ian's answer and if I ALSO need tab2 columns then this answer (with possibly some duplicate rows). Am I correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: My answer is probably a little more generalist yes. Ian answer create a big geometry with tab2 geoms, and select the rows of tab1 that intersects with it. It can have performance issue if your tables start to become big. With a join, you can do more things and have better performance with proper indexes on your geom. And like I said if you want lines only one time, you can use distinct. I think you can do that with exists too, I will edit my answer to add it.

Comment: Thank you. It's clear now. And I think using CTE makes the SQL command neat. If it's not too much -  could you explain how to use CTE with `ST_collect` for this example for the sake of completeness. I can't seem to correctly formulate it and keep getting errors. Thanks.

Comment: Probably something like that : `WITH collected AS (
  SELECT ST_Collect(geom) as geom FROM tab2 WHERE "cond_column" = 'selected_string'
)
SELECT
  *
FROM tab1, collected
WHERE ST_Intersects(tab1.geom, collected.geom)`

Comment: I get the following error - 'Relate Operation called with a LWGEOMCOLLECTION type.  This is unsupported.' Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: try `ST_Collect((ST_Dump(geom)).geom)` or just try one of the query I did, for example the last

Answer (score 3):

You need to group them together into a single "geometry" which is what `ST_Intersects` is expecting (not a series of geometries which is what you have). Look at [`ST_Collect`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) for a solution to this. It allows you to do things like:

```
SELECT ST_Collect( ARRAY( SELECT geom FROM sometable ) );
```

and

```
SELECT stusps, ST_Collect(f.geom) as geom
FROM (SELECT stusps, (ST_Dump(geom)).geom As geom
            FROM
            somestatetable ) As f
GROUP BY stusps
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am finding it difficult to understand the second example. Would you mind explaining that, if possible using `tab1`, `tab2`?